# How to order a composite index to prevent insertion deadlocks?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have a mysql (actually MariaDB 5.5.52) database described roughly as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, 
    col1 INT, 
    col2 VARCHAR(32), 
    col3 VARCAHR(128), 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
    UNIQUE KEY index1 (col1, col2, col3)
);
```

There are more columns, but all are inside the `UNIQUE` key, and there are no other keys in the table.

I run a multiple threads of a python script that inserts into this database. Each thread does around 100-1000 inserts using mysql.connector's `executemany` such as

```
ins_string = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 ({0}) VALUES ({1});"
cursor.executemany(ins_string.format(fields, string_symbols), values)
```

I run into consistent deadlock problems. I presume that these problems are caused because each thread locks between rows of table1 in some semi-random order based on the order in which my python list `values` is generated. This is somewhat validated by testing; when I build a new database from scratch using 24 threads, the deadlock rate per `executemany()` statement is > 80%, but by the time there are a million+ rows in the database the deadlock rate is near zero.

I had considered the possibility that the deadlock is a result of threads competing for AUTOINCREMENT, but in the default InnoDB 'consecutive' lock mode, it doesn't seem like this should happen. Each thread is supposed to get a [table level lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) until the end of the INSERT. However, the way the AUTOINCREMENT and INSERT locks interact is confusing to me, so if I have this wrong, please let me know.

So if the problem is caused by the random-ish ordering of the unique key, I need some way of ordering the insert statements in python before passing them to MySql. The index is hashed in some way by MySql, and then ordered. How I can replicate the hashing/ordering in python?

I'm asking about a solution to my diagnosis of the problem here, but if you see that my diagnosis is wrong, again, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why have `ID`, since you have a `UNIQUE` key that could be promoted to `PRIMARY`?

Regardless, sort the bulk insert rows on `(col1, col2, col3)` before building the `executemany`.

If that is not sufficient, then decrease the number of rows in each `executemany`.  100 rows gets within about 10% of the theoretical best.  If 100 decreases the frequency of deadlocks below, say 10%, then you are probably very close to the optimal balance between speed of bulk loading and slowdown due to replaying deadlocks.

How many CPU cores do you have?

Are there other indexes you are not showing us?  *Every* `UNIQUE` index factors into this problem.  Non-unique indexes are not a problem.  Please provide the full `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: There are eight columns, all of which are in the UNIQUE index; otherwise that is the full `CREATE TABLE` statement. The `id` column exists to be the foreign key for a variety of sub-tables. I never run more threads than I have CPU cores, generally I'm on 48-core servers while limiting to 24 threads or less (there are other processes going on as well).

Comment: @kingledion -- OK; those answers seem reasonable.  So, I vote for (1) pre-sorting the rows for executemany and (2) smaller batches.  Fewer than 24 threads might help avoid deadlocks somewhat, but get less work done -- can't predict whether it is worth doing.  What version of MySQL?  Old versions were inefficient at 24 threads.

Comment: It is MariaDB 5.5.52. I suppose I should mention it is MariaDB... What constitutes an 'old' version?

Comment: MariaDB 5.5 and MySQL 5.5 were pretty close.  I don't recall for sure, but it seems like 16 threads would be safer.  5.7 (10.2) is when 48 became feasible.